# Jinja: Is it a better practice to use the {% url %} tag or explicitly define the url?

Tags: django, jinja2

Say you have a forums app in Django, with the namespace `forums` and the homepage has the name `home`, and you want to make a `<a>` tag link to that page. Would it be a better practice to do `<a href="{% url 'forums:home' %}"></a>`, or would it be better to do `<a href="/forums"></a>`? Or would this not matter?

Comment: btw, just for correctness you are not using Jinja. You are probably using Django templates which is not the same thing as Jinja templates. Django does support Jinja templates now however in that case `{% url %}` template tag is not available. more at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/templates/#module-django.template.backends.jinja2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The `{% url %}` tag will always point to the canonical url. In your example, when following common Django conventions, the second form would result in an unnecessary redirect from `/forums` to `/forums/`.
- The `{% url %}` tag is a fail-fast system. Django will raise an error if an url doesn't exist when creating the url - not when the user clicks on the link and gets a 404. This helps to develop error-free applications.
- Like Mikko said, it allows you to change the url for a view without changing every template.

Answer (score 3):

`{% url %}` tag exists to be used - it is not there for nothing.

If you move views around manually fixing all of your template code to point to new views is painful.